# <div> with height=100% only fills one 'screenful'

Tags: css

Please check the following example:

> http://www.esaer.com.br/csstest/

If the vertical scrollbar doesn't appear, please resize the window so it does. Problem is: when you scroll down, the portion of the screen that was hidden does not show the blue div background, which has height 100%, even though the red div forces the height of the 'page' overall be greater than one screen.

I want the blue background to span the entire page, even if the page is bigger than one screen. How can I make that happen? (I've been suggested a javascript solution already, but would prefer a css-only approach)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solved" the issue by forcing a certain height (bigger than the fixed-size element) and living with the limitations.

Thank you for all the answers, though, they might be helpful in some other situations!

Answer (score 2):

Does the inner element matter? If not:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html, body { height:100%; }
#main-div { min-height:100%; width:400px; margin:0 auto; background:blue; }

<body><div id="main-div">test</div></body>
```

Comment: In fact, it does matter, since it's what is causing the scroll in the first place... edited the page to reflect a few of your modifications though...

Comment: If it's flexible enough I'd opt for the background on html element.

Answer (score 2):

100% mean 100% of the viewable area, i.e. the screen size so this is working as designed.

What you might be interested in is [**position: fixed**](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp) although iirc older IEs have some issues with this: [ref](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html), [ref2](http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/)

Answer (score 2):

If you use padding in the main div and then use a relative position in the inner div it could probably work, I'm not quite sure if you want this behavior at all, hopefully this could get you a little closer to what you looking for.

```
#main-div {
    background:blue none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height:100%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    padding:20;
}
#sub-div {
    background:red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height:200px;
    left:50px;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>CSS Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }

    #main-div {
        width: 400px;
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10%;
        background: blue;
    }

    #sub-div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 400px;
        background: red;
    }
    #container{
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        overflow-x:scroll;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-div"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="sub-div"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works great. However, this takes the scrollbars out of place, which is undesireable...

Comment: You're right, the horizontal scroll was screwed up. I fixed it.